# Samsung Galaxy S5 - When I open activity from broadcast receiver activity not open some time

Tags: android, galaxy, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to open an activity (Application) from broadcast receiver, below code is working fine on maximum devices.Specifically on Samsung Galaxy S5. The activity launches sometime and sometimes it doesn't launch.

The issue only occurs in Samsung Galaxy S5:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(context,Activity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    Log.e("app launch--", "application launch code call");
```

Comment: what does "activity launch some time" mean.

Comment: application launch randomly with this code, but on other devices its running fine

Comment: If just the new activity launches different, maby you have a different defalt animation there.

Comment: i don't think so, because  it is working fine on other device, and i also did debug i am not  getting any exception, code execute properly,
it is device specific issue.

Comment: Does your `Log.e()` statement get executed every time?

Comment: yes it is execute every time.

Answer (score 0):

Please add one more thing, open wake lock before call activity.
for Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received.

```
 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        //Object flags;
        if (wl == null)
            wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "MATH_ALARM");
        wl.acquire();
```

and when your activity finish release wake lock

```
try {
            if (wl != null)
                wl.release();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and Add this permission in your manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

may it will work for you